# A second search results page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, search

On my WP site I have a custom post type, and have modified the loop so that the results display as markers on a Google Map. I would like these results searchable.

To do this I need a second search page template, (so that I can display the search results on the map). Getting a custom post type search is easy - but I can't find any hint of whether I can create a second site search template. Is there a way to, say, create a second search page that uses "/x?=" instead of "/s?="...

I'm simply trying to scope out whether I'm wasting my time looking for a solution - does anyone have an idea whether this is even possible?!

Comment: This post may help you with your question. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89886/how-to-create-a-custom-search-for-custom-post-type

Comment: Perfect - worked like a charm. Thanks!